# How to return new field from cakephp beforeMarshal

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So i have a REST API that is expecting a json string containing a field, eg, 'status'.  I need to relate this string to the ID and have successfully obtained the ID using the beforeMarshal in the Table model:

```
$query = $status->find()
        ->where (['status' => 'new']);

    $id = $query->first();
    $data['status_id'] .= $id->id;
```

Problem with the above, is `$data['status_id']` will not work because 'status_id' is not actually in the incoming fields.

How can i add 'status_id' into the $data field, or return it from beforeMarshal, such that it REPLACES the 'status' string value ?

Ie, incoming: `{"status": "new"}`, before saving entity, I need to get `{"status_id": "2"}`

This is cakephp v3

Comment: The ID you need to relate to is that coming from another table?

Comment: "_... because 'status_id' is not actually in the incoming fields_" How exactly is that a problem? And why are you using the [concatenating assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)?

Comment: You have stated in your other question that you've solved this problem in, in that case please add the solution here as an answer and accept it later on, so that the question appears resolved for future readers. Thanks!